# Set default value in custom picker in blackberry cascades using qml

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, picker, blackberry-cascades

I have created a picker that shows list of countries and it works fine. Currently by default the first country is selected. I need to change it to another country. How should I do that?

This is the picker I created

```
 Picker {
            id: picker
            title: "Select your country"
            expanded:true
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill
            // A DataModel is used to populate the picker.
            dataModel: XmlDataModel {
                source: "Model/CountryCodes.xml"
            }

            // Picker items are set up similarly as to how its done in a ListView.
            pickerItemComponents: [
                PickerItemComponent {
                    type: "country"
                    content: Container {
                        background: Color.create("#9B59B6")
                        layout: DockLayout {
                        }
                        Label {
                            multiline: true
                            maxWidth:  1000
                            text: pickerItemData.name
                            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

                            textStyle {

                                base:SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BodyText
                                color: Color.White
                                fontSize: FontSize.PointValue
                                fontSizeValue: 10.0
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.Normal
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]

                       onSelectedValueChanged: {
                // These are the currently selected indexes.
                var index0 = picker.selectedIndex(0);
                var type = dataModel.data([0, picker.selectedIndex(0)]);

                console.log("Selected index:"+index0);
                countryCode.mainText="+"+type.phoneCode;
            }    

        }
```

My countrycodes.xml is in this format

```
  <model>
  <column loop="false" colspan="3" >
  <country code='af' phoneCode='93' name='Afghanistan' />
  <country code='al' phoneCode='355' name='Albania' />
  ........all other countries.....
  </column> 
  </model>
```

Currently Afganistan shows selected all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this, it loads which one from settings. This is placed in `onCreationCompleted`

```
picker.select(0, app.getValueFor("backImageID", 0));
```

and the second element is like this

```
picker.select(1, app.getValueFor("fontColorID", 0));
```

Comment: I need to set the country at 100th index so I tried picker.select(0,100) but it shows the error - init has not been finished before PickerPrivate::selectedIndex(). Any advice??

Comment: picker ID goes from 0, while database ID goes from 1. So make sure you use 99 ID. Otherwise I haven't seen that error yet, maybe you try to set selected item before it's done?

Comment: I tried to set it oncreationcompleted of picker as well as the page also, and there are over 200 countries in the list so the 100th index will definitely be there.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue was but I set the picker value on timer with 100ms duration and oncreation complete I called the timer and it worked :)

Comment: Also try in XmlDataModel if you can set selected in onItemAdded